# Dialogflow CX - Keeping Date Parameters in Page Transitions

Tags: parameters, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I'm having this issue in dialogflow cx where the only problem is that my transition route keeps the parameter value like "
{ "day": 1, "month": 1, "year": 2024 } ADDED" but will only go to the next page if i send the date twice!

Can anyone help me? Would really appreciate any advices or solutions...thanks everyone

I have created a test flow for a small form with only 2 or 3 pages: "CaptureStartDate" and "CaptureEndDate" and each of them should keep a date parameter so i'm using @sys.date as an Entity Type and I named the parameter from CaptureStartDate "startdate", checked the required box and went to route conditions and did a "Match AT LEAST ONE rule (OR)" with "$session.params.startdate != null" for the transition to the second page (CaptureEndDate).